# Get data from Web Api in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am using a Web Api with the following data in a controller.

```
 public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "Item1", "Item2s", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5" };
        }
```

I would like to get this data from the Web Api in an application. I used this  code to get data from another controller:

```
public IEnumerable<Items> GetItems()
        {
            return repository.GetItems();
        }
```

The above shows the controller code, that gets a list of Items specified in the web api. 
How do I alter the following code to get data from the string[] instead?

```
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:1234/api/items");

            var items = new List<Items>();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Parse 1 Product from the content
                var ItemsSet= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);

               // Data from Api 
                var ItemData = new Items
                (
                (string)ItemsSet[0], 
                (string)ItemsSet[1],
                (string)ItemsSet[2],
                (string)ItemsSet[3],
                (string)ItemsSet[4]


                );

                items.Add(ItemData);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:1234/api/items");

var Items = new List<Items>();

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    IEnumerable<string> categories = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>();

    var ItemData = new Items
            (
                // Use this category list to initialize your Items
            );

    items.Add(ItemData);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, also I made an edit to the code, I made a mistake. It should be  `items.Add(ItemData);`

Comment: Several because I have to add the the array values to the `Items` object. Hence the `new List<Items>();`

Comment: How do you want to convert a collection of string to a collection if Items ? If i understand you well, your service returns IEnumerable<string>, and those strings become Items in your calling method ? Do you have one Items per string value ?

Comment: The IEnumerable<string> actually gets a list of values using a linq query. It is supposed to return a list pf all values in a column.         `public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return repository.GetAllProducts()
                                     .Select(p => p.Category).Distinct();

        }`  I would like to populate ItemData variable with all the values from the column retrieved in the linq query. Aslo, see the code for the edit made to correct. That is, `var ItemData = new Items`

Comment: What i find confusing is that you get categories, then you set properties like `Id`, `Name`, `ImagePath` when you get the response. See my edited answer if it gets closer to your need.

Comment: Actually I changed the code to the edited above. This is what I'm using now. But I have the same problem, only returning 1.

Comment: I also getting that same error so tell me have got any soluation this @Réda Mattar